# How to configure class specific log level in GWT logging?

Tags: gwt, logging

When using java.util.logging, the log level for a specific class (i.e. for a child logger with the name of the class) can be configured in the logging.properties file as so:

```
com.foobar.MyClass.level = FINE
```

I create the child logger in MyClass using the class name as follows:

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

The parent logger's log level is set at SEVERE. This causes FINE level logging only for MyClass to be logged, with SEVERE level logging happening everywhere else.

Is there a way to configure this similarly in the Google Web Toolkit gwt.xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. GWT Logging support is limited in that you can only set the log level at the module level. I would love to see better control over logging in future releases, but AFAIK, there aren't any serious plans to expand such support.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that might be the case, but always like to err on the side of ignorance and ask. Still a great framework.

Comment: @CBass Did this answer meet your needs? If so, please indicate that by [accepting it as the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).